# How to draw network diagrams with lua and tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, lua, harftex

I was reading [this article](https://archive.fosdem.org/2015/schedule/event/algorithmic_graph_drawing_in_tikz/) on drawing with `lua` and `tikz`. On page 45 of the article, the author's given an example code demonstrating the way to do so. Here's his `lua` code:

```
-- File SimpleDemo.lua
local MyAlgorithmClass = {}
function MyAlgorithmClass:run()
    local g = self.digraph
    local alpha = (2 * math.pi) / #g.vertices
    local radius = g.options.radius
    for i,vertex in ipairs(g.vertices) do
        vertex.pos.x = radius * math.cos(i * alpha)
        vertex.pos.y = radius * math.sin(i * alpha)
    end
end

-- "Publish" the algorithm
local graph_drawing_framework = require "pgf.gd.interface.InterfaceToAlgorithms"
graph_drawing_framework.declare{
    key = "simple demo layout",
    algorithm = MyAlgorithmClass,
    preconditions = { connected = true }
}
```

and on the following pages he's added four `tikz{…}` code to show the output. 3rd example gives me the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/stub' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Here's my `tex` document with the 3rd example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, mindmap}
\usegdlibrary{SimpleDemo}

\begin{document}
    \tikz \graph [ simple demo layout, radius=1cm]{
        a --[orient=right] b -- c -- a;
        d -- e;
        f -- g -- h -- d --[stub,red] f;
        e --[stub, red] g;
    };
\end{document}
```

`graphs, graphdrawing, mindmap` libraries resolved issues for other 3 examples. Which one do I have to add to resolve the issue of 3rd example?

Comment: Does the problem also occur when you put the extension in the require, i.e., `\directlua{require("SimpleDemo.lua")}`?

Comment: Could be a custom style I suppose. If you add a placeholder like `\tikzset{stub/.style={{}}` does it work as expected?

Comment: Sorry, brace error. Remove one opening brace after style. Or just remove stub from the code, that’s just as easy for testing.

Comment: Was just opening it. (It's not an article, but a set of slides for a presentation.) You're sort of asking the wrong question though. You've done the Lua part, which does the positioning of the nodes, that works, and isn't really relevant for the problem, I think. What you want to know is how to define a TikZ style `stub` which changes how a path between two nodes is drawn in a specific manner. Looks like the middle part of the path is cut out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is one possible definition of a `stub` style which does something similar to what is seen in the slides you refer to. I used one of the built-in positioning algorithms, but that shouldn't matter for the line style. Slide 46 indicates how you can change the style of the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, calc} % <-- added the calc library
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\tikzset{stub/.style={
  to path={%
      (\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztostart)!0.3!(\tikztotarget)$)
      ($(\tikztostart)!0.7!(\tikztotarget)$) -- (\tikztotarget)
      }
}}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \graph [ simple necklace layout, radius=1cm, nodes={circle,draw=blue!80,fill=blue!10}]{
        d -- e;
        f -- g -- h -- d --[stub,red] f;
        e --[stub, red] g;
    };
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what I've done when I was experimenting flowcharts. I've seen one doing like those `/.style …` on YouTube! Can we set these styles in `lua`?

Comment: @EmonHaque Why do you want that? Such a style contains TikZ-options, using TikZ syntax.

Comment: Someone wrote that there are other libraries like `kpse`, `node`, etc. besides `tex` e.g. `tex.print`. I thought there are something like `node.draw`, `node.shape`, etc. to help us avoid those tex syntax. Are there any actually?

Comment: @EmonHaque  No idea.

Comment: I've found an example of using `lua node` and posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494307/can-we-draw-tikz-node-with-lua-this-way)