# Can we draw tikz node with lua node this way?

Tags: luatex, lua, harftex

I've found [this example](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX) of using `lua node`. To output `Va` they've:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
        local g1 = node.new("glyph")
        g1.font = font.current()
        g1.lang = tex.language
        g1.char = 86

        local g2 = node.new("glyph")
        g2.font = font.current()
        g2.lang = tex.language
        g2.char = 97

        g1.next = g2
        g2.prev = g1

        local hbox = node.hpack(g1)
        local vbox = node.vpack(hbox)
        node.write(vbox)
}
\end{document}
```

Can we draw `tikz` node like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz[node distance = 3cm]{
        \node (a) at (0,0) [draw, circle] {A};
        \node (b) [below of = a, draw, circle] {B};
        \draw [<->] (a) to (b);
    }
\end{document}
```

to produce this:

[image]

using `lua node`?

Comment: despite the similarity in name there is no connection between nodes in lua and in tikz. It would be a _lot_ (thousands of lines I guess) of work to recreate the tikz logic in lua, so you are almost certainly going to just want to print the tex string from lua and interpret it as tex.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tp=tex.print
tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}")
tp("\\node (a) at (0,0) [draw, circle] {A};")
tp("\\node (b) [below of = a, draw, circle,node distance=3cm] {B};")
tp("\\draw [<->] (a) to (b);")
tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think  those `tex.print` and `tex.sprint` are for formatting plaint text, tables, etc.. These works really well for those purposes BUT for `tikz node` I think `lua node` is a good candidate.